# OBIEE Case Statement

Tags: if-statement, obiee, case-statement

I'm trying to use a Case formula to evaluate a date but it's erroring out every time. Not sure where I'm going wrong.

1/1/9999 is a date.

Code:

CASE
WHEN "Item "."Store OOS" = 1/1/9999
THEN 'repln'
ELSE 'Fashion'
END

Comment: quote `'` between `1/1/9999`?

Comment: Is "Store OOS" of type datetime?

Comment: Hi Eric- Adding quote ' to 1/1/9999 still errors outs. "Store OOS"  output is a datetime.

Comment: Nick can you close the question please if the response helped you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CASE WHEN "Item"."Store OOS" = date '9999-01-01' then 'repln' ELSE 'Fashion' END

Comment: This code worked. Good to know that Oracle is date specific case as well.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "is date specific case". You just have to be precise with data type handling. Nothing...numeric. Single quotes...string. Date...date.

And can you close the question please?